# How to find the Row in the html table using jquery 

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Iam adding a new row on click of a button and that row contains 3 textboxes and one select buutton .How do I make the textboxes and select box values  to null of that newly added row .

```
$('#table').find("sno_'+i'").val('');
```

Here "i " is dynamically generated row.But this is not working.

Comment: Could you post the HTML that is appended to the table dynamically? With that, we can work on some answers :-)

Comment: And/or please let us know what .find("sno_'+i'") is looking for. A class (then there's a dot missing) or an id (then there's a hash missing) or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're appending it as the *last* row and you want to clear *all* the form element value, you could just do this:

```
$('#table tr:last :input').val('');
```

If you need to limit it to the text and select inputs, do this:

```
$('#table tr:last').find(':text,:select').val('');
```

Beyond that, your question is not very clear. If `i` is the index of the row, then do:

```
$('#table tr').eq(i).find(':text,:select').val('');
```

If `i` has been appended to a class on the row, then do this:

```
$('#table tr.sno_' + i).find(':text,:select').val('');
```

If `i` has been appended to the ID attribute on the row, then do this:

```
$('#sno_' + i).find(':text,:select').val('');
```

Comment: won't that also clear the text of the select button? maybe `input:text` would be better

Comment: @patrick:I need to find the Row with the value "i"  and then apply the values null.

Comment: @hunter: Yes, though at one point OP calls it a select button, but then he calls it a select box. We're definitely lacking some details.

Comment: @Someone: What do you mean by *the value "i"*? Is that the index of the row? Has the value of "i" been added to its ID attribute? Or a class attribute?

Comment: @patrick :yes patrick "i " is  the index of the  row .it has been added to id attribute appended with sno.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever it means, at first glance the `+i` should go outside quotes:

```
.find("sno_" +i)
```